# Insert / Update Multiple Fields of Every Record From Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, user-defined-functions

Creating a temporary table and I need to insert 20 amount fields.  The first 10 will come from a table valued function using some of the fields from the source table as parameters.  The second 10 will come from the same function, using the same field values from the source table, but passing different values for the two year and date related parameters.

Either I have not come up with the right question to find the answer or my knowledge level is preventing me from seeing how an answer would work for my need.

The table and the function do not have a common field to use, for example, in a join.  The function simply takes values from a table record, calculating and returning the 10 amounts.

How do I obtain the amounts needed during the insert or a subsequent update?

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##NumHealthDeps') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##NumHealthDeps

    Create table ##NumHealthDeps (DNum int, DUnit int,
    Social varchar(9), RecID int, MedPlan varchar(12), MedPrem numeric(6,2),
    RetCode varchar(3), DepTypes varchar(2), HDepCount int, CompAmt numeric(6,2),
    F1Amt numeric(6,2), F2Amt numeric(6,2), P1Amt numeric(6,2), P2Amt numeric(6,2),
    P3Amt numeric(6,2),
    D1Amt numeric(6,2), D2Amt numeric(6,2), D3Amt numeric(6,2),
    D4Amt numeric(6,2), NewCompAmt numeric(6,2), NewF1Amt numeric(6,2),
    NewF2Amt numeric(6,2), NewP1Amt numeric(6,2), NewP2Amt numeric(6,2),
    NewP3Amt numeric(6,2), NewD1Amt numeric(6,2), NewD2Amt numeric(6,2),
    NewD3Amt numeric(6,2), NewD4Amt numeric(6,2))

    INSERT INTO ##NumHealthDeps
(DNum, DUnit, Social, RecID, MedPlan, MedPrem, RetCode, DepTypes, HDepCount,
CompAmt, F1Amt, F2Amt, P1Amt, P2Amt, P3Amt, D1Amt, D2Amt, D3Amt, D4Amt,
NewCompAmt, NewF1Amt, NewF2Amt, NewP1Amt, NewP2Amt, NewP3Amt, NewD1Amt,
NewD2Amt, NewD3Amt, NewD4Amt)
SELECT nev2.DistrictNumber, DistrictClassification, Ssn, nev2.SubscribersCount,
nev2.CurrentPlanId_1, nev2.CurPlan12PayRate_1,
nev2.RetireesRateCode_1 + nev2.RetireesRateCode_2 + nev2.RetireesRateCode_3,
'  ',
COUNT(DependentsLastName) AS 'NumDeps',
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00,
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
FROM NVEligViewForAccess nev2
LEFT OUTER JOIN NVDepViewForAccess
ON Ssn = SubSsn
AND SubscribersCount = SubCnt
WHERE ActiveCoverageYears = 20162017
AND nev2.CurEffDate_1 > 0
AND nev2.CurTermDate_1 = 0
AND SUBSTRING(nev2.CurrentPlanId_1,1,2) NOT IN ('KA','EA','HM')
AND nev2.CurrentPlanId_1 NOT LIKE '0%'
AND nev2.DistrictClassification != 6
AND nev2.DistrictNumber < 7000
AND (
    DepNum IS NULL
    OR (
        DepEffHeaCoverageDate_1 > 0
        AND DepTerHeaCoverageDate_1 = 0
        )
    )
GROUP BY nev2.DistrictNumber, DistrictClassification, Ssn, nev2.SubscribersCount,
nev2.CurrentPlanId_1, nev2.CurPlan12PayRate_1,
nev2.RetireesRateCode_1 + nev2.RetireesRateCode_2 + nev2.RetireesRateCode_3
ORDER BY nev2.DistrictNumber, DistrictClassification, Ssn
```

The following code shows the function call and parameters passed using year and date related values for the first 10 amount fields.  All of the named parameters are fields from the NVEligViewForAccess table.

```
    dbo.GetAllPPORatesForPlanFunc(20162017, DistrictNumber, 'H',
    CurrentPlanId_1, '', DistrictClassification,
    CASE 
        WHEN DistrictClassification < 5
        OR DistrictClassification BETWEEN 10 AND 49
        OR DistrictClassification BETWEEN 71 AND 74 THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
    END,
    'N',
    CASE
        WHEN DistrictClassification < 5
        OR DistrictClassification BETWEEN 10 AND 49
        OR DistrictClassification BETWEEN 71 AND 74 THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN RetireesRateCode_1 = ' '
            AND RetireesRateCode_2 = ' '
            AND RetireesRateCode_3 = ' ' THEN 'ACT'
        ELSE RetireesRateCode_1 + RetireesRateCode_2 + RetireesRateCode_3
    END,
    Ssn, 0, 0, CAST('10/1/2016' AS datetime), NULL)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You posted a huge wall of text but not much of anything in the way of details. I can't even figure out what the question is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point that catched my attention is when you wrote "The table and the function do not have a common field to use, for example, in a join".

This scenario can be solved with the use of "cross apply". Cross apply is similar to a join, however it doesn't require a key. For each record on one side it executes the other side and relates the result with the initial record.

For example:

```
Select * from mytable
Cross apply  dbo.myTableFunction(mytable.fieldparameter)
```

Once you are able to join the table and the function, I think you just need to build an insert upon this instruction.

Comment: I had found some answers referencing cross apply but did not relate it as a possible solution.  Thank you for taking the time and for pointing out that cross apply is the solution.  I tried it and it worked perfectly.